# Using a DLink 615 router but can't make Samsung Bd C6500 recognize wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dvd, hdtv, high-definition

Using a DLink 615 router but can't make Samsung Bd C6500 recognize wireless network

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Firmware do you have installed on the DLink-615?  I have this same router, and a different Samsung wireless printer and could never get them to connect properly until the other day when I discovered that the DLink-615 "Check Now" button for updates was BROKEN in the version I had. (*It always reported that I had the latest even though it was almost 3 years out of date!*)

Depending on the revision of your hardware, the latest version of the firmware is up to 3.13NA as of today (March 13, 2011)

The fixes to the firmware include important updates like being able to recognize devices with a MAC address that does not start "00" which **all** but one of my wireless devices does not. (and many other fixes)

I'd recommend you go to the [DLink site for the DIR-615 router](http://www.dlink.ca/products/?pid=565) and install the latest firmware for your model.